# How do I return JSON data from stored procedure via MySQL Workbench to NodeJS API

Tags: mysql, database, mysql-workbench, multiple-tables, jsonparser

I have created a stored procedure, which has a task to return category related information from serveral tables. Also the SP will do some logic, filtering and mapping. At the end I would like to return the final data as JSON object.

I will select data from 2 tables as below :-

select * from category_details;

select * from category_filters;

I would like to get response in NodeJS

```
{
    categoryDetails: {
        // whatever I get from "select * from category_details;"
    },
    categoryFilters: select * from category_filters; // as this will be an array
}
```

I am getting response as below

```
[
   [// whatever I get from "select * from category_details;"],
   [// whatever I get from "select * from category_filters;"]
]
```

Comment: What's your question about this? Why do you want to use NodeJS **and** MySQL workbench?

Comment: I am using NodeJS as backend for creating APIs and MySQL as Database.

Comment: Please add all details to your question by editing it. Your title says "via MySQL Workbench", your question itself doesn't even mention Workbench

Comment: So, I am using MySQL package in my NodeJS Application, via that package, I am connecting to my Database. In my NodeJS application, I am calling my stored procedure.

Comment: Please add all clarification to your question by editing it. You haven't explained what the problem is

Comment: Sorry for that, I just added, what I am getting and what I am expecting.

Comment: I still don't get the problem. Please share the code you are using, such that others can reproduce your problem. Also, check the tagging - is this really a problem related to Workbench or any JSON parser?

Comment: The question is not clear at all. Please show the part of your code to see how you are trying to get the data.